# expdp command gives error on Ubuntu server for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle18c, expdp, data-dump

I've been trying to export oracle datadump with "expdp" utility in Oracle 18c. I've set the environment variables under ~/.bashrc as following

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/ubuntu/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
export ORACLE_SID=ORCL
export ORACLE_BASE=/home/ubuntu/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0/opt/oracle/product
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

When I enter the command "expdp" in terminal - it keep saying your ORACLE_HOME is not set

```
root@ip-172-30-xx-xxx:~# expdp
UDE-00013: Message 13 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UDE
UDE-00019: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

I'm new to Oracle Database at present. What could be the possible issue ? Do I need to set environment variables at some other places too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Oracle XE is not really supported on Ubuntu: if you really want to use Oracle, install it on Oracle Linux (freely available): you will never see Oracle Database running in *real* production on Debian or Ubuntu and you will need to use Oracle Linux or RedHat Linux or Suse Linux.

Do not run Oracle utilities as root: you don't need to and it is generally a bad practice on Linux to use root account when it is not needed.  Use a non privileged account to run Oracle utilities like SQL*Plus or Data Pump and make sure that your Oracle settings are run for each shell session: putting them in .bash_profile for the right account should be enough.

For this specific error message just make sure that ORACLE_HOME is correctly set: it is likely that your .bashrc has not been run.